# Why is my script printing the wrog messages?

Tags: windows, batch

I am working with a script that has two possible choices: Y= yes/operation 1 and N= no/cancel operation. Whenever I choose yes, the message for cancel is printed first, *then* operation 1 is executed. I want the proper messages to only appear for the corresponding choices. Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

:choice
echo.
echo Do you want to proceed with the process?
echo Enter Y to run or N to cancel.
set /p :choice=
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :YES
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :NO

:NO
echo The operation has been cancelled...
PAUSE
goto :END

:YES
:: Additional code for operation 1 goes here.

echo The operation has been completed successfully!
PAUSE

:END
```

Comment: You are setting the variable `choice` but checking the variable `c`. That doesn't seem right to me. I'm also not sure why you have a colon before "choice".

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow... When you say _"checking the variable `c`"_ are you referencing `"%c%`? I'm still new to making user-choice code...

Comment: As well as your accepted answer, you may like to consider using the [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), which creates an alternative and possibly more natural dialogue for a Yes/No query: `choice /m "Do you want to continue"`, followed by `goto ch%errorlevel%`, with labels `:ch1` for Yes and `:ch2` for No. Note that the example in the link is wrong for the current version of `cmd`, which requires quotes when there are spaces in the prompt, as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set /p varName=` will prompt you to enter a value to be saved in `varName`. Your `if` statements need to check `varName` rather than something completely different.

Currently you are setting `:choice` and checking `c`. (%c%)

Try changing

```
set /p :choice= 
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :YES 
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :NO
```

To

```
set /p choice= 
if /I "%choice%" EQU "Y" goto :YES 
if /I "%choice%" EQU "N" goto :NO
```

Note that in my example I have also removed the ":" before the "choice" in your `set /p` command as it seems unnecessary and would mean that your `if` statements would need to be `if /I "%:choice%"`

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I made such a small mistake. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries, the syntax for batch commands can be particularly obtuse at times.